# Trying convert JSON to spacy training format for NER, but not getting any input or error

Tags: json, nlp, stanford-nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to convert data turks NER Json file to spacy training format using the following code but upon executing the code not giving any input.

```
import plac
import logging
import argparse
import sys
import os
import json
import pickle
import spacy

dataturks_JSON_FilePath = Path("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Project\\Spacy")

def convert_dataturks_to_spacy(dataturks_JSON_FilePath):
    try:
        training_data = []
        lines=[]
        with open(dataturks_JSON_FilePath, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            data = json.loads(line)
            text = data['content']
            entities = []

            for annotation in data['annotation']:

                point = annotation['points'][0]
                labels = annotation['label']

                if not isinstance(labels, list):
                    labels = [labels]

                for label in labels:
                    entities.append((point['start'], point['end'] + 1 ,label))


            training_data.append((text, {"entities" : entities}))
        return training_data
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Unable to process "+dataturks_JSON_FilePath +"\n"+"error = "+str(e))
        return None
```

No input upon executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function *convert_dataturks_to_spacy* but never called it. So, it doesn't get executed and you see nothing when you run it.

In case you are calling the function, ensure that you are including json as input. It seems there is a random folder *C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Spacy* in the above code.